# Clicking with element on other element

Tags: javascript, jquery, leap-motion

I know it sounds silly, but what I want to do is trigger click with some html element hovering over another element.

Lets say we got .cursor that is hovering anchor text. In this case click on .cursor should open a google page.

```
<div class="cursor"></div> 
<div class="htmlPage">
    <a href="www.google.com">Google</a>
    <a href="www.facebook.com">Faccebook</a>
     <a href="www.stackoverflow.com">Stack</a>
</div>
```

Any ideas how to do that?

**and this don't count**

```
$('.cursor').click(function(){
     $('.htmlPage a').click();
})
```

Cursor should be movable and should be able to click on other links.

[image: Cursor on google]

Cursor is that blue circle hovering Google button.
Here I have cursor on google, now on click this should link to google, If i were to click on stack then stack should have opened.

Comment: What do you mean by `Cursor should be movable and should be able to click on other links`? Cursor will be movable, no restrictions on that are made

Comment: I just added a picture that could explain some more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are not using IE you can use `pointer-events:none` in CSS. Then your element will be unresponsive to any mouse interaction (and acting like a ghost foreground element).

The workaround for IE is someting like that:

```
var x = event.pageX;
var y = event.pageY;
$('.cursor').hide();
var here = document.elementFromPoint(x, y);
$('.cursor').show();
// Do what you want with the element here
// Find the parent a element needed with here.parentNode and here.tagName === "A"
// And then fire the click function
```

I've never use jQuery but I think it should work.

Hope it could help

Comment: I think you can even fire the onclick function to the here element directly as it would bubble to the a element

Comment: I was going to answer my own question with this. And best trick here is that you get object and you can trigger click and all other mouse effects.

Answer (score 1):

you can try to get the ".cursor" position on click and compare to each ".htmlPage a" positions and change the window.location.href with the one of the element that overlaps

```
$(".cursor").click(function(){
    var cursor=$(this);
    var cl = cursor.offset().left;
    var cr = cl+cursor.width();
    var ct = cursor.offset().top;
    var cb = ct+cursor.height();
    $(".htmlPage a").each(function(){
        var page=$(this);
        var pl = page.offset().left;
        var pr = pl+page.width();
        var pt = page.offset().top;
        var pb = pt+page.height();
        if(((cl>pl&&cl<pr)||(cr>pl&&cr<pr))&&((ct>pt&&ct<pb)||(cb>pt&&cb<pb))){
            window.location.href=page.attr("href");
        }        
    });
}).draggable();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/EUmeB/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ANVUC/1/)

```
// Target link in the next div, following div.cursor
$("div.cursor").click(function() {
    var link = $(this).next(".htmlPage").children("a").attr("href");
    window.location.href = link;
});
```

Comment: Biggest problem here is that you can't access all the links. You can't trigger element below(under) cursor.

Comment: I see... hopefully this demo will help

Comment: There can be only one cursor.

Comment: How is this being moved? Is user dragging it? Or does it just follow cursor?

Comment: Its leap motion controled. But you can look it as its dragged.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.cursor').click(function(){
     $('.htmlPage a').click();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Attach an event handler to the cursor class.

```
$('.cursor').on('click',function()
{
    window.location.href = $(this).siblings('.htmlPage').attr('href');
}
```

This gets the sibling of the element and makes the location equal to that sibling

Answer (score 0):

To be a little more explicit, this might be best.

```
$('.cursor').click(function(){
  $(this).next().children('a').click();
});
```